# eclipse - find references only in specific class and all subclasses of that class

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to find the references to external method say Foo.getInstance() in specific type hierarchy, basically i want to restrict the search results to specific class and all subclasses, i am not interested in all references. Is it possible to do with eclipse or any custom plugin? Thanks

Comment: You can do this creating a working set with only the files holding your hierarchy (if they're in a package this is the easiest way). Then CTRL+H and Java Search with scope (Working Set). If the classes are all within a package you can select that in Project Explorer then perform Java Search with scope "Selected".

Comment: @BigMike: Make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this creating a working set with only the files holding your hierarchy.
Then `CTRL+H` and Java Search with scope "Working Set".

If the classes are all within a package you can select that in Project Explorer then perform Java Search with scope "Selected".

Working sets are awesome

Comment: yes, but How can you achieve the O.P. goal if some sub-classes are outside that package? Am I missing something?

Comment: working set may contain different files (across different projects). If classes resides in different packages simply add to the ws each file you need to monitor. AFAIK there's no limit to the number of working set you can define in eclipse. However if the hierarchy is in just one package, searching within selected item (via selected scope in java search dialog), is simpler.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Maybe the OP wanted to find a reference automatically in all subclasses in the current working set, without specifing manually where you want to search and where you don't. Anyway I think your answer is the only possible way.. AFAIK

Comment: there's also the hierarchy view, but it's full classpath scoped as well as the "Find all ref." (ctrl+shift+g) command. I heavily use working sets in my projects to keep everything clean, once got used to, it saves lots of time. Expecially now that I'm working on a near million lines of code legacy project written by people using java as it was PHP...

Comment: probably this is the only one way, but still i am looking for some kind of plugin that allows to do this, and don't want to create working sets. anyway IDEA has this functionality out of the box.

Comment: will try to dig in a little further, maybe there's something already for that, writing a simple Java Search extension which select classes should not be so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified a workaround. Requires viewing eclipse search results(in "show as list" mode).

For example ClassA has several subclasses (ClassB,C..Z) which inherits methodA defined on class A and calls them.

Perform method reference in eclipse and change the view to "show as list" using triangle/View menu appearing on top-right corner. This will list method signatures containing super-class/sub-class references so you can easily pick or drop from the search result.

If there are too many results to filter through you can  Copy this onto file editor and use search keyword of subclass name (ClassB) and each line containing classB is a potential result which calls methodA on classB object.

Note: If method signature uses classA object reference and within body it type-casts to classB then you need to pick that entry and not drop it. I'd also recommend working set approach mentioned above. This is alternate approach to the question posted.